# I don't understand the error message in declaration the avl tree

Tags: c++

I'm trying to program an AVL tree and I got this error that I don't understand, can someone help. Thank you

[source](http://www.flipcode.com/archives/AVL_Tree_Template.shtml)

[image]

```
template<class KeyType, class ItemType>
class AVL
{
 protected:
 template<class KeyType, class ItemType>
 class AVLNode
 {
  public:
  AVLNode(KeyType key, ItemType item) :
  m_Balance(0), m_Depth(0),
  m_Key(key), m_Data(item),
  m_pLeft(0), m_pRight(0)
  {
  }

  KeyType       m_Key;
  ItemType  m_Data;

  AVLNode*  m_pLeft;
  AVLNode*  m_pRight;
  };

  AVLNode<KeyType, ItemType>* m_pRoot;
  public:
  AVL() : m_pRoot(0) { }
  ~AVL() { }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try it with these changes:**

```
template<class KeyType, class ItemType>
class AVL
{
 protected:
 // Unnecessary -> template<class KeyType, class ItemType>
 class AVLNode
 {
  public:
     AVLNode(KeyType key, ItemType item) : m_Balance(0), m_Depth(0),
                                           m_Key(key), m_Data(item),
                                           m_pLeft(0), m_pRight(0)
  { }

  private:
     int m_Balance;  // Missing from the ctor declaration
     int m_Depth;  // Missing from the ctor declaration
     KeyType m_Key;
     ItemType m_Data;

     AVLNode<KeyType, ItemType>*  m_pLeft;  // Change here
     AVLNode<KeyType, ItemType>*  m_pRight; // Change here
  };

  AVLNode<KeyType, ItemType>* m_pRoot;
  public:
  AVL() : m_pRoot(0) { }
  ~AVL() { }
};
```

Comment: That sounds like some unrelated error with an image.

Comment: I copied the code from [link](http://www.flipcode.com/archives/AVL_Tree_Template.shtml), and I think the part on the image cause problem.